# Special relativity velocity addition formula precision

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, computational-physics, approximations, software

I tested the special relativity addition formula
$$u_{\text{total}}=\frac{v+u}{1+\frac{vu}{c^2}}$$
and
found that addition of small numbers converges to smaller speed, but bigger numbers to bigger speeds.

For example:

- addition 0.5 + 0.5 gives 0.8, but 0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1 gives ~ 0.763
- addition 0.0000001000 with iterations count 10000000 gives ~ 0.761594

Is such behavior expected for the special relativity addition formula?

I use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void relative_speed(uint32_t iters_count, long double v_delta, uint64_t c)
{
    long double v_sum = 0.0;
    long double u = 0.0;
    long double v = 0.0;
    long double u_quoted = v_delta;
    unsigned int i = 1;
    for( ; i <= iters_count ; ++i)
    {
        v_sum += v_delta;
        u = (v + u_quoted) / ((long double)1.0 + v * u_quoted / (c*c));
        v = u;
    }
    printf("v =%.20Lf v_delta=%.10Lf v_sum=%Lf iterations=%u\n", v, v_delta, v_sum, i-1);
}

int main()
{
    relative_speed(2, 0.5, 1);
    relative_speed(5, 0.2, 1);
    relative_speed(10, 0.1, 1);
    relative_speed(100, 0.01, 1);
    relative_speed(1000, 0.001, 1);
    relative_speed(10*1000*1000, 0.0000001, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code review aside, in physical terms you're contrasting $\tanh(n\operatorname{artanh}(v_\Delta/c))$ with $nv_\Delta/c$. [Rapidity is additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity#Lorentz_boost).

Comment: This is a math question, not physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is explicitly nonlinear, so you shouldn't be surprised that when you apply it multiple times it behaves quite differently than when you apply it twice with bigger numbers.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you.